# DAX - Nested Calculated queries

Tags: nested, dax

I have a large data file (4.2mil rows and 10 columns) and I'm trying to do some filtering with measures. However, when I try to use nested measures everything explodes and I'm not really sure why.

So far, I have two explicit measures:

```
MaxValue:=MAX('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value])
```

and

```
MaxIndex:=
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Index],1),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Element Forces - Area Shells' ),
        'Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value]=MAX('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value])
    )
)
```

This works and I get a correct values. However, as I see it, I should be able to put the MaxValue measure into the MaxIndex measure, but then everything just stops.

The new measure I'm picturing should look like this:

```
MaxIndex:=
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Index],1),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Element Forces - Area Shells' ),
        'Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value]=[MaxValue])
    )
)
```

But it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't test it right now, I think it's caused by the implicit context transition*. When you're referencing a measure in another measure, internally a CALCULATE() is involved and therefor a context transition. That's not wat you want in this case. I advise you to use a variable, in order to create one measure:

```
MaxIndex:=
VAR MaxValue = MAX('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Index],1),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Element Forces - Area Shells' ),
        'Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value] = MaxValue )
    )
)
```

Note: I'm not sure, please forgive me if I'm wrong :)

In addition, the use of VAR, from the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/var-dax):

> This feature is included in SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services (SSAS), Power Pivot in Excel 2016, and Power BI Desktop only. Information provided here is subject to change.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I may have been a bit confused. I thought DAX was only used in PowerPivot, but by googling a bit I can see it's used for Visual Studio which I assume the peace of code you just wrote should be used for?

If I copy it into an explicit measure cell in PowerPivot I get an error message saying it's incomplete, but I don't think PowerPivot will accept a syntax with definitions?

Comment: DAX is used in PowerPivot, SQL Server Analysis Service (Tabular) and PowerBI. Which version of PowerPivot are you using? Variables are supporting since 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/var-dax

Comment: ah bugger, my company is still on the 2013 version, we hope to upgrade in the near future, but unfortunately my project doesn't allow me to wait for that.

Comment: But the second measure is working fine right? So you can't use variables or a nested measure, but it's producing correct values?

Comment: Well sort of. I would like to use the second measure in another measure later on, but as it is right now, I just have to copy the formula in the the next measures which just snowballs and creates some extremely large and unmanageable formulas.

Also everything becomes extremely slow.

Comment: IdF11:=Calculate(Firstnonblank('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value],1),FILTER(all('Element Forces - Area Shells'),'Element Forces - Area Shells'[Attribute]="F11"),Filter(all('Element Forces - Area Shells'),'Element Forces - Area Shells'[Index]=Calculate(FIRSTNONBLANK('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Index],1),filter(all('Element Forces - Area Shells'),'Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value]=max('Element Forces - Area Shells'[Value])))))